# I find no drivers for my Cpu ( Amd a8-7410 )

Tags: drivers, 64-bit, amd-processor

Can someone help me to find the right drivers for the AMD A8-7410?
When I look at the AMD webpage I find no drivers for the A8-7410.

Comment: Here's the magic of GNU/Linux: you finally don't need drivers for your CPU!

Comment: Why do you believe drivers are needed for a specific CPU?

Comment: I have been working on Windows for years. And would now like to upgrade to linux and on some pages they say you can get problems if you can not find the right drivers for your system.

Answer (score 0):

The way you formulated it in the comment it's true for any system. But CPU don't need drivers. Upon a computer powered on CPU executes BIOS/UEFI code. This code does basic initialization of hw, and looks for devices to boot from. Execution then goes to bootloader code of the default boot device. Bootloader then *(I omit irrelevant parts, like choosing an OS to load)* loads initramfs which contains kernel drivers and utilities needed to continue booting; like ext4 driver to read the underlying ext4 file system *(otherwise you'd get into the paradox: to read the filesystem you need a driver, but the driver is in the filesystem)*. Then goes a usual boot process, like initializing some more hw, starting systemd daemons, etc, you can easily find it on the internet.

Note: nowhere your CPU needs a driver, it's a fundamental part of a computer that just works.

**NB**: your CPU has embedded GPU, which might need drivers, but you don't need to worry about them. FTR, GPU drivers consist of kernel and userspace driver *(for better security, maintenance, and usability)*. Kernel drivers are just shipped with the kernel. Userspace part for AMD and Intel is called "Mesa", and Ubuntu has it shipped by default.

Some useful links for you to read:

1. [More-or-less friendly description of changes in Linux kernel releases](https://kernelnewbies.org/LinuxVersions)
2. [Ubuntu vs Windows, AMD benchmarks](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=radeonsi-win-catching&num=1) *(and you can query on google different terms you see there to get more understanding of how things work)*.